# How to get a list of all films on Wikidata?

Tags: freebase, wikidata-api

I was using Freebase to get all movies/films there for my website, but it's getting shut down soon. so I was searching for another free database for movies and came across Wikidata. To be honest it's too complicated to understand how to query all the movies.

So I thought you guys could help me to get all the movies in Wikidata. In the future I want to include TV shows and series as well.

Programming language doesn't matter, I want to use web query with a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can look for all the entities that are an instance of film, which in Wikidata is translated as:

[P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) (instance of) -> [Q11424](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11424) (film)

For the moment, the best way to do this query is to use the wdq.wmflabs.org API, where this query translate as: `http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:11424]` (avoid making this query in a browser as it will probably make it crash due to the ). At the moment I'm writting, this requests returns 157038 items in the form of numeric ids (ex: `125`). To get the Wikidata ids, just add a leading `Q` -> `Q125`.

To get the labels and data from all those Wikidata ids, use the Wikidata API `wbgetentities` action: `https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q180736&format=json&languages=en`.
Beware of the 50 entities per-query limit though

[UPDATE] Wikidata now offers a [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparql) endpoints: [the same query in SPARQL](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20v%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fq%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fq%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%0A%7D) or even this [same query but also including subclasses of films](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fq%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fq%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ11424%0A%7D)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but is there any paging when i get all the ids ? in freebase i could limit queries per page and then get the current page cursor to do the paging later. is this possible ?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, but if you need to get absolutely all the films at once, you might rather have a look at wikidata dumps https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download#JSON_dumps_.28recommended.29 and extract a subset of it: `cat dump.json |grep '11424\,' > films.json`, see what I did there https://github.com/inventaire/inventaire-authors-birthday

Comment: If you're thinking of using this for a production application, note that the referenced API is an experimental one which will probably be retired when there's a production Wikidata query API available.

Comment: i tried to use the bash command but i got a file with 73 KB and there was only ~30 items which are not even films. [link](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:11424]) gives different items which are also not movies. I dont understand why is it so complicated.

Comment: Have also found some entries which are instances of Q24869(feature film). The classification is not as accurate as I would like either